# Example of continuous function whose Newtonian potential is not twice differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

I was reading Gilbarg & Trudinger and in there is a statement that the Newtonian potential of a continuous function need not be twice differentiable.

I would appreciate it if someone could provide me an example that would help me to understand this concept properly.

Edit: The Newtonian potential of $f$ is defined as

$$w(x)=\int_{R^n}\Gamma(x-y)f(y)dy$$

where $\Gamma $ is fundamental solution of Laplacian equation.

Comment: Perhaps include a link defining Newtonian potential of a function.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I missed to Include. Please have a look

Comment: Such an example is given in Gilbarg & Trudinger, this is Problem 4.9 (a) in Chapter 4.